# glm model with normal distribution and log link

Tags: r, regression, glm

In a university assignment I have a negative intercept in my lm regression, which makes my model hard to interpret. My supervisor advised me to try glm model a normal distribution and a log link in R to force my model to have a non negative intercept.

I have tried the following two ways with the glm and gamlss functions:

`model1 <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = "log"))`

`model2 <- gamlss(y ~ x, family=NO, data=df, mu.link= "log")`

Both of them keep giving negative intercepts. Does anyone have an idea what I do wrong?

Comment: The negative intercept in on the linear scale, not the logged scale.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I looked online and in the material I got from my course and I could not find a linear link. What package should I look for to get this?

Comment: Not a linear link, the link is still log. The equation for a glm  is `g(y) = X * beta`. The right hand side, `X * beta` is called the "linear predictor". In this case you are using `g(y) = log(y)`, a log link. The linear predictor terms, including the intercept, are still unbounded real numbers. But if you transform a prediction back to the unlogged scale, `y_hat = exp(X * beta)`, the predicted `y_hat` will be always positive, because `exp()` is always positive. So your negative coefficient estimate for the intercept, `beta0`, corresponds to a predicted intercept value of `exp(beta0)`.

Comment: Have a look at [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function), perhaps. By default, if you use the `predict()` method on your model, R will evaluate the linear predictor (log-scale for y). If you use `predict(..., type = "response")` R will apply the inverse link for you to get back to the untransformed `y` scale.